# Can we define time as a field?

Tags: spacetime, coordinate-systems, field-theory, time

The main objective is, can we relate time in terms of a field, I know time differs in many properties from an usual field. But I always imagine time as an forward moving field and we all know it is affected by gravitational field, so can we relate time as a field?

Comment: Time is that which the clocks show, so if you want to have a time field, then you have to place a clock in every point in space.

Comment: For your information, time exists before the clocks and it not the property of clock it is the property of space.

Comment: I am not sure the time and frequency divisions at NIST will agree with you on that completely. What spacetime provides is the causality that allows us to synchronize clocks, but it does not provide "time" itself.

Comment: no we can't do that because it depends on the observable, not only from the point in the space

Comment: Surely you can only define time in a given reference frame ? Since there is no preferred reference frame there is no preferred time co-ordinate.

Comment: @FlatterMann A magnetic field exists even if we don't place compasses at every point in space. A field is more an expectation of what we would measure if we actually placed a measuring device at those points.

Comment: *time as an forward moving field* Moving forward through what?

Comment: @KDP A magnetic field changes the spectral lines of an atom placed in it. Time doesn't. Whether it's 4pm or 7:35am is completely irrelevant for physics. I would not agree that a physical field is "just" an abstract expectation value. I think it's even worse than that, though, because an actual clock defines a rest system. If we place a clock in every point in space, then we have a preferred matter background that breaks relativity and we are back to Galilean physics. That is what I was trying to hint at. The early universe might represent that kind of system, but I am not a relativist.

Comment: *we always imagine time as an forward moving field* Who is “we”? I imagine no such thing.

Comment: Why would you want to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A field is a quantity which typically depends on the location like --- giving a simple example --- a temperature distribution over a piece of metal, on one end of the metal the temperature is low and other end the temperature is high.
So the temperature is a function of the location where it is measured:

$$T = T(x)$$

That would be a temperature field.

In particular the temperature distribution can be predicted by physical laws, i.e. there is a relationship between a temperature value at a certain position and the temperature value in its neighourhood.

Of course on top of that one could be interested in the temperature distribution in time and location, i.e.

$$T =T(t,x)$$

On the other hand time is just a parameter, nothing more. Time depends on the chosen reference system, but not on the location.

One can make consider slices of spacetime where the time is the same, these slices depend on the reference system.
Different observers at different locations have their proper time they measure, but one would never consider this as a field. Simply since there is no relationship between the individual (proper) times and the location where it is measured, rather it depends on the reference systems of the different observers. In particular each observer can choose its own reference system, which means that such a data set would  be rather arbitrary.

Comment: I think your statement is completely wrong. I, standing here on Earth could easily look out at the universe and map the different rates of time when compared to my time, surrounding each Galaxy and each planet in exactly the same way that I could say the temperature at each point in the universe is so many degrees higher or lower than my own.  And any other person in the universe could do exactly the same from their point of view. So time, or the rate of time, could easily be described as a field.

Comment: @foolishmuse But the observations of time depend on the observer and how they are moving. So there is no single "time field".

Comment: @gandalf61 that is only true in special relativity for kinetic time dilation. That is not correct for general relativity and gravitational time dilation. That is not dependent on the Observer.

Comment: @foolishmuse But if there was a single time at each point in space then the twins in the twins "paradox" would be the same age when they met again.

Comment: @foolishmuse At the position of each planet I have in my "table of data" I choose another reference system (than the rest system of the considered planet) which moves at a (completely) different speed than the planet, I get for the same position a very different time. Yes, I can set up such a table, but the data they contain would be of no physical interest.

Comment: @gandalf61   The Twin Paradox is a special relativity thing.  We are dealing with General Relativity; the warping of spacetime caused by mass/energy.

Comment: @FredericThomas  You are also mixing up special and general relativity.  Gravitational time dilation (general relativity) is not concerned with the speed of the planet or galaxy. It is only related to mass/energy, or basically the mass of the planet or galaxy.  This knowledge and the ability to do these measurements was the key aspect of the movie Intersteller where they travelled to a planet near a black hole.  They knew that they would outlive their family at home.

Comment: @foolishmuse SR is just a limiting case of GR. If your idea of a universal "time field" won't work in SR then it won't work in GR either.

Comment: @gandalf61 SR and GR are related.  But anyone, traveling at any speed relative to anyone else or relative to a planet, would understand a map that shows that a black hole has greater time dilation than a large planet which in turn has greater time dilation than a smaller planet which has greater time dilation than distant space.   So in answer to the OP, gravitational time dilation can indeed be mapped out across the universe, and thus can be considered a field in the normal sense.

Comment: @foolishmuse This is a general question and my answer is a general answer. A reference system can be chosen that it moves close to speed of light WRT a given rest system of a planet. The clock will take into account SRT time dilation and the effect given by the metric, the clock measuring will not distinguish between both effects.

Comment: @FredericThomas That would be same thing as saying "because I keep the temperature in my car at 30C, I can't draw a map of temperature while driving across the country because my thermometer doesn't differentiate."   The speed at which you are traveling has no impact on the time dilation on planet A compared to star B compared to black hole C.   Thus they can be mapped and considered a field.  This is getting to be too long a discussion for these comment posts.

Comment: @gandalf61 The electric field and magnetic field are observer dependent, eg the magnetic field can completely disappear in some reference frames, so it follows a field does not have to be observer independent to qualify as a field.

Comment: @KDP Well, yes, obviously we can define a field in any arbitrary way that we like. "Distance from my current location" is a field. But a field that is observer dependent is not a physically useful entity. Which is precisely why we combine the electric and magnetic fields into the electromagnetic tensor.

Answer (score 8):

A field is just a function that is defined at each event in spacetime. So we could define a field $$f(t,x,y,z)=t$$ This would be time as a field.

> we always imagine time as if a forward moving field

Fields don’t move, and this field doesn’t even have waves.

Note: there are two primary concepts of time. Proper time is the physical time measured by a clock. Coordinate time is the mathematical time defined in some coordinate systems.

This field would represent coordinate time. As such it is coordinate dependent and therefore often considered to be non-physical. It doesn’t obey any important field equations, so yes it can be treated as a field in a formal sense, but doing so does not bring any benefit that I can see.

Comment: Around a Schwarzschild blackhole, time would ticking a different rates according to distance from the gravitational source according to the observer at 'infinity' no?  I think it would effectively be the same as the gravitational potential field offhand.

Comment: @KDP for spacetimes that have a timelike Killing vector and for coordinates that respect that symmetry, yes

Comment: I appreciate your answer, we can conclude that obviously there is no absolute time and to represent coordinate time system we have to be specific about the obeserver. For different observer there must be different expression for coordinate time.

Comment: @Ash yes, and sometimes even just specifying the observer is insufficient. E.g. for non-inertial observers there is no single coordinate system accepted as representing their frame